# Idle memory increased about 20% after recent ubuntu 16.04 update

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, updates, ram, memory-usage

I updated my system to get latest firefox 70 using the usual method.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Before the update my system's idle memory usage was near 30 percentage and after the new update its jumped to 50% a near 20% jump from the usual. The odd thing I noticed is that after the completion of update my systems memory instantly jumped above 70 percentage and my system's fan started running at very high speed. I immediately restarted my computer and after the restart the idle system memory is stuck at 50 percentage. I used `top` to find any unusual process but I don't see any drastic changes in my processes.

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit, It was an app running in the background. I have used `ps aux` command to find high memory using process and then disabled the problem causing daemon.